# How to `docker login` to OpenShift Docker registry

Tags: azure, docker, openshift, docker-registry, openshift-client-tools

I am using Redhat OpenShift 4.4.17 deployed in Azure.

I logged in to OpenShift as administrator.

I have a Docker image locally, now I need to push my docker image to OpenShift Docker registry.

I am using below command

```
docker login -u <user_name> -p `oc whoami -t` image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000
```

I am getting error as:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/v2/: dial tcp: lookup image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc: no such host"

What can I try to resolve this?

please see this one:

$ oc get route -n openshift-image-registry

```
 NAME                HOST/PORT
```

default-route        default-route-openshift-image-registry.

PATH      SERVICES         PORT      TERMINATION   WILDCARD

```
       image-registry   <all>     reencrypt     None
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000` can not be resolved at the external of the Openshift cluster, because it's internal registry service name.
So you should access to the internal registry service through the Route hostname of the registry in order to do `docker login`. Refer [Exposing a secure registry manually](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.4/registry/securing-exposing-registry.html), if the internal registry was not exposed.

```
// expose the internal registry to external using Route.
$ oc patch configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io/cluster --patch '{"spec":{"defaultRoute":true}}' --type=merge

// Verify the internal registry Route hostname.
$ oc get route -n openshift-image-registry
NAME            HOST/PORT                                                            PATH   SERVICES         PORT    TERMINATION   WILDCARD
default-route   default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.clustername.basedomain            image-registry   <all>   reencrypt     None

// Try to login using the internal registry Route hostname.
$ docker login -u <user_name> -p $(oc whoami -t) default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.clustername.basedomain
```

Here is my test evidence using podman as follows.
First of all, you should place and update the trusted CA of your Router wildcard certificates on your client host which is executed the docker or podman client.

```
# podman login  -u admin -p $(oc whoami -t) default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.<clustername>.<basedomain>
Login Succeeded!
```

Additionally, if you face "x509: certificate signed by unknown authority" error message, then you should place the Router trusted CA on your host or should use "--tls-verify=false" in podman case or the same option for docker case instead of that.

```
# podman login  -u admin -p $(oc whoami -t) default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.<clustername>.<basedomain>
Error: error authenticating creds for "default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.<clustername>.<basedomain>": pinging docker registry returned: Get https://default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.<clustername>.<basedomain>/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

# podman login --tls-verify=false  -u admin -p $(oc whoami -t) default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.<clustername>.<basedomain>
Login Succeeded!
```

Comment: oc patch configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io/cluster --patch '{"spec":{"defaultRoute":true}}' --type=merge \n 

running this  command is giving me the " config "cluster" not patched " .......what does this mean............


I am a newb and m sure I m missing something please connect my dots

Comment: @Balakrishna If you already configured as "defaultRoute: true", it's not patched. You can check the current config using "oc get configs.imageregistry.operator.openshift.io/cluster -o yaml", or check whether the Route of the image registry is existing or not using "oc get route -n openshift-image-registry".

Comment: please see this one:

 oc get route -n openshift-image-registry
NAME            HOST/PORT                                              PATH      SERVICES         PORT      TERMINATION   WILDCARD
default-route   default-route-openshift-image-registry.<domain-name>            image-registry   <all>     reencrypt     None,

I have updated in question, incase you dont understand in this comment.

I have this one present but still not able to login or push  any image...

please suggest, Thanks in advance @Daein

Comment: $ docker login -u <user_name> -p $(oc whoami -t) default-route-openshift-image-registry.apps.clustername.basedomain.................This command giving me authenticationn required , what additional authentication I need to provide for this one???? @Daein

Comment: @Balakrishna I updated my answer with test evidence and more guide around CA error. I think you may meet the trusted CA error at the moment.

Comment: Thanks man, I am able to push the image succesfully to my registry.....But I got another problem, my pods are not getting the image from there , ImagePullBackOff error is coming, do i need to do any additional configuration to create my pods................................I am sorry I am a newb so please help

Comment: @Balakrishna I think you had better create another case for your new issue with some outputs.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64513173/i-have-pushed-my-docker-images-from-local-to-openshift-registry-but-my-pods-unab